# 1-surgery on the figure-eight knot: reference request

Tags: reference-request, geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

As far as I know, 1-surgery on the figure-eight knot gives ($\pm$) the Brieskorn sphere $\Sigma(2,3,7)$. However, is there a citeable source for this? Sometimes Thurston's notes are mentioned, but I couldn't find a statement that the result of the surgery is this particular space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what might be the earliest spot where it's mentioned, but you could refer [Example 1.4](https://books.google.com/books?id=hUZmqAfaX6AC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=figure%20eight%20knot%20surgery%20brieskorn&source=bl&ots=cLP8hSZksQ&sig=2pdHcQ8XfpFwO5WTuSYMGYXdPK8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=caguVYSlIoKWNrPYgcgJ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=figure%20eight%20knot%20surgery%20brieskorn&f=false) from Saveliev's book *"Invariants of Homology 3-Spheres"*.